# How to put an image inside a button that created in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a simple project using bootstrap. I have this code that can create a button inside a dataTable and it is working fine. I try to put an image to it `not glyphicons` by the code that I provided below as you can see.. But it's not working. But the `glyphicon` icon in First button is working.

```
{ data: "ActionMenu", title: "Test", sClass: "alignCenter","mRender": function (data) {
   return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md action" id="checkId"><i class="fa fa-dollar fa-fw action"></i></button>'
   + '&nbsp; <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md action" id="checkId2" src="Images/TestPicture.png"></button>';
}
```

Comment: "But it's not working" what do you mean ? can you see the image if you access to it directly ? does the console say anything ?

Comment: @gobes I don't have any error in console. What I mean in not working the Image that I provided using the code is not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't give a `src` to a `button` element. Try to put an `<img>` element inside the button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md action" id="checkId2">
    <img src="Images/TestPicture.png"/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <button id="imageId type="button"><img src="path/of/image"></button>
```

*Appy css with the help of ID if required*